# PrimeFaces PickList

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using PickList which containts my bean list Country[Country -> Region -> Company].The problem is when i'm casting the picklist.getTarget() value into Country it throws class cast exception. I'm using Country converter as well. I don't know what is the problem?

Here my code,

### XHTML:

```
<p:pickList id="pickListId" required="true"
    value="#{countryBean.countryDualModel}" var="avlCountry"
    itemValue="#{avlCountry}"
    itemLabel="#{avlCountry.region.company.companyName}"
    converter="#{countryDualListConverter}" showCheckbox="true"
    showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true"
    filterMatchMode="contains">
    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{countryBean.transferEvent}"></p:ajax>
    <p:column style="width:75%;">#{avlCountry.region.company.companyName}</p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

### Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value="bizEntityDualListConverter")
public class BizEntityDualListConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        Object ret = null;
        if (arg1 instanceof PickList) {
            Object dualList = ((PickList) arg1).getValue();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            DualListModel<Country> dl = (DualListModel<Country>) dualList;
            for (Object o : dl.getSource()) {
                String id = "" + ((Country) o).getRegion().getCompanyId();
                if (arg2.equals(id)) {
                    ret = o;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(Object o : dl.getTarget()){
                String id = "" + ((Country) o).getRegion().getCompanyId();
                if(arg2.equals(id)){
                    ret = o;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ret == null)
                for (Object o : dl.getTarget()) {
                    String id = "" + ((Country) o).getRegion().getCompanyId();
                    if (arg2.equals(id)) {
                        ret = o;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        String str = "";
        if (arg2 instanceof Country) {
            str = "" + ((Country) arg2)..getRegion().getCompanyId();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

### CountryBean:

Popuate DualListModel:

DualListModel countryDualModel = new DualListModel<>(sourceCountryList,targetCountryList);

### OnTransfer Listener:

```
public void transferEvent(TransferEvent event){
    int size = countryDualModel .getTarget().size();
    for(Country ctry : (Country) countryDualModel .getTarget()){
        //
    }
}
```

//When it comes here, it throws class cast exception says,java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.test.Country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing converter name `converter="#{countryDualListConverter}"`? 
Change to `converter="#{bizEntityDualListConverter}"`.

You can also use [Ominifaces's ListIndexConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListIndexConverter). It is a nice `JSF Utility`.

Comment: Yes i found out already now its working fine, but the thing is i've given the converter as type instead of value. If i give as a value it won't works